# Stack and pop() function in C

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation

During an exercise, I've encountered an error:

This is a piece of code of the evaluation function

```
second_element = (*(long int*)upo_stack_top(stack));
upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);
first_element = (*(long int*)upo_stack_top(stack));
upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);
```

In this function, when an operator is found, I must take the last two values, pop it from the stack, compute the operation and save the result onto the stack.
But, there's the issue... the top of the stack doesn't change at all (even if, in the pop() function, the top is managed).
This is the pop() function code:

```
void upo_stack_pop(upo_stack_t stack, int destroy_data)
{
    if(!upo_stack_is_empty(stack))
    {
        upo_stack_node_t *node = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        stack->size -= 1;
        if(destroy_data)
        {
            free(node->data);
        }
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Usually it works well, but in this case no...

I've no idea where's the problem...

EDIT:

```
push, pop and top stack's functions:

void upo_stack_push(upo_stack_t stack, void *data)
{
    if(stack != NULL)
    {
        upo_stack_node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(upo_stack_node_t));
        if(node == NULL)
        {
            perror("Unable to create a stack node");
            abort();
        }

        node->data = data;
        node->next = stack->top;
        stack->top = node;
        stack->size += 1;   
    }
}

void upo_stack_pop(upo_stack_t stack, int destroy_data)
{
    if(!upo_stack_is_empty(stack))
    {
        upo_stack_node_t *node = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        stack->size -= 1;
        if(destroy_data)
        {
            free(node->data);
        }
        free(node);
    }
}

void* upo_stack_top(const upo_stack_t stack)
{
    if(upo_stack_is_empty(stack))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return stack->top->data;
}
```

And these are the node and stack structs:

```
struct upo_stack_node_s
{
    void *data;
    struct upo_stack_node_s *next;
};
typedef struct upo_stack_node_s upo_stack_node_t;

struct upo_stack_s
{
    upo_stack_node_t *top; 
    size_t size;
};
```

So, with some test functions, it works:

```
void test_push_pop()
{
    int value = 1;
    upo_stack_t stack;

    stack = upo_stack_create();

    upo_stack_push(stack, &value);

    assert( upo_stack_size(stack) == 1 );

    upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);

    assert( upo_stack_size(stack) == 0 );

    upo_stack_destroy(stack, 0);
}

void test_top()
{
    int value1 = 1;
    int value2 = 2;
    upo_stack_t stack;

    stack = upo_stack_create();

    upo_stack_push(stack, &value1);
    upo_stack_push(stack, &value2);

    assert( upo_stack_top(stack) != NULL );
    assert( *((int*) upo_stack_top(stack)) == value2 );

    upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);

    assert( upo_stack_top(stack) != NULL );
    assert( *((int*) upo_stack_top(stack)) == value1 );

    upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);

    assert( upo_stack_top(stack) == NULL );

    upo_stack_destroy(stack, 0);
}
```

But, with the function of the exercise, it doesn't work...

```
int eval_postfix(const char *expr, long *res)
{
    upo_stack_t stack = upo_stack_create();

    if(stack != NULL)
    {
        long int symbol;
        const char *e = expr;
        int num_elements;
        long int *first_element = NULL;
        long int *second_element = NULL;

        while(*e != '\0')
        {
            sscanf(e, "%ld", &symbol);

            if(isdigit(*e))
            {
                upo_stack_push(stack, &symbol);
            }
            else if(!isdigit(*e))
            {
                if(isspace(*e))
                {
                    ++e;
                    continue;
                }

                second_element = (long int*)upo_stack_top(stack);
                upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);
                first_element = (long int*)upo_stack_top(stack);
                upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);

                switch(*e)
                {
                    case '+':
                        *res = (*first_element) + (*second_element);
                        upo_stack_push(stack, res);
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        *res = (*first_element) - (*second_element);
                        upo_stack_push(stack, res);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        *res = (*first_element) * (*second_element);
                        upo_stack_push(stack, res);
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        *res = (*first_element) / (*second_element);
                        upo_stack_push(stack, res);
                        break;
                    case '^':
                        *res = (long int)pow((*first_element), (*second_element));
                        upo_stack_push(stack, res);
                        break;
                    case '%':
                        *res = (*first_element) % (*second_element);
                        upo_stack_push(stack, res);
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("Unknown operator\n");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                perror("Malformed expressions");
                return *res;
            }

            num_elements = upo_stack_size(stack);
            ++e;
        }

        if(num_elements == 1)
        {
            res = (long int*)upo_stack_top(stack);
            upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);
            upo_stack_destroy(stack, 0);
            return *res;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Malformed expressions");
            upo_stack_destroy(stack, 0);
            return *res;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typedef-ing *pointers* to structs is usually a bad idea, especially if `upo_stack_node_t` is a struct, and `upo_stack_t` is a pointer to a struct. Post a [mcve], including code for `upo_stack_pop`, otherwise it's hard to give a suggestion. Casting to `upo_stack_node_t*` to `long int*` is certainly wrong, and your remark that it "usually works well" might indicate that you have a problem elsewhere.